В динамической библиотеке нет имён — в чём магия?
Начинаю на обывательском уровне копаться в устройстве библиотек. Решил для одной (динамической, python runtime) глянуть список имён (через nm) – выпал в осадок: их там нет.
Ведь компилятор берёт имена функций из заголовочного файла и ищет их в библиотеке. А если как-то иначе, если библиотека действительно не содержит именных меток, то как возможны такие чудеса оптимизации? В тексте библиотеки на самом деле сокрыта таблица соответствий имён функций и их адресов в файле?
Ответьте, кто знаком с устройством. Dynamic ELF

Используйте nm с ключом -D для динамических библиотек! Не знал. Теперь всё выводит как нужно!

Это раз. А два - можно импортировать функции по индексу в таблице. То есть, теоретически можно сделать динамическую библиотеку без имён. Думаю, такое всякие безопасники любят.
